# Pycharm does not active existing virtual environment

Tags: linux, pycharm, linux-mint, python-venv

Pycharm does not activate existing virtual environments. When I select it in the list of possible venvs and click OK it just does some loading and does not close the window. The venv is not activated.

The only way to get a proper `venv` working is to start a new project have Pycharm create it when starting the project. Otherwise it does not work.

I have upgraded Pycharm many times suspect that older versions are messing something up.

Comment: This is wrong for a number of reasons, the only PyCharm option to automatically activate the venv for you is if there's one single open project in the project view and the default interpreter for that project is set. In that case in `settings` > `tools` > `terminal` there is an option for the venv to activate when you launch a terminal tab. The other possibility would be to run code without a run configuration created in which case a temporary run config with the default interpreter is created.

Comment: Both the above cases (which are limited in their application - one single project or no chosen run configuration) are not clearly explained in your answer. And both can be achieved by correct use of the functionalities with no need to reset any configuration files. There is also nothing new about any of this, these functionalities are exactly like before.

Answer (score 2):

**Tldr:
Delete Pycharm's config directory found in `~/.config/JetBrains`**

For other OS the locations are [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#logs-directory)

Wanted to answer my own question since this has been bugging me for weeks on end.

I tried deleting Pycharm's cache directory, it did not the fix the problem.

But after I deleted the entire config directory it fixed the problem. I am pretty sure some of the icons in the new project wizard also changed, point to dross from old versions of Pycharm messing things up for me.